# Regex Replace the number only the first time it appears in a sequence

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-bigquery

i have a number sequence **4191159999** and i want to replace with regex only the first occurence of the **9** number for a **88** (to result in 41881159999).

i tried `(O9;"(9.+?)";"8")` but it results in **4181588**, also tried `(O9;"^\d{2}9+";"8")` but it deletes the first two numbers resulting in **81159999** and i cant use Negative lookahead with bigquery or google sheets...

Comment: You could also just use =substitute(4191159999,"9","88",1)  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace:

```
^        # Match at the start of the string
([^9]*)  # a capturing group of 0 or more non-'9' characters,
9        # then a literal '9'.
```

...with:

```
$188
```

in which `$1` is the non-`9` sequence we captured, and `88` means literal `88`.

Try it [on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/IytSwD/1).

Try it:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const regex = /^([^9]*)9/;
const text = '4191159999';

console.log(text.replace(regex, '$188'));
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @ViniciusOliveira If you have found an answer that solves your problem, please mark it as accepted. Any other problems should be posted separately as new questions.

Comment: Thanks, it worked on sheets, when i tried on bigquery it didn't, i searched and found that to use on BQ you have to replace the $1 for \\1 to refer the capture group.

Answer (score 1):

In google sheets for example, you can start capturing optional digits 0-8 in group 1 using `([0-8]*)`

Then match a single 9, and in the replacement use group 1 followed by 88

```
^([0-8]*)9
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zVneCW/1).

Example:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(TO_TEXT(A1), "^([0-8]*)9", "$188")
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log('4191159999'.replace(/9/, 88));
```